Do early termination fees hold up in court?
Adobe is being sued by the FTC for including an unadvertised 50% early termination fee (ETF) in their “annual paid monthly” plan. The FTC seeks to have Adobe recompense the users, make cancellation easy and efficient, ban similar practices, and even personally punish the executives responsible for this fee.
I used to view these fees as normal and fair - in the B2B world, it's common to even have a 100% fee. But now I wonder if I've been wrong. The FTC seems to believe that this can violate ROSCA, when a service is advertised at its annual-paid-monthly price, or that the ETF might be a penalty clause (which are non-enforceable). I wonder - how strong is the legal status of such fees as of today?
This question is only about cases where the Provider has no actual damages from the early termination, other than expected future payments from one small Customer. In Adobe's case, they have 33 million subscribers, growing at 10 per minute, and runs on AWS, so one customer doesn't affect their plans or sizing. When can the Provider successfully collect this fee, and when are they out of luck? Here are some example situations I see:

Chargebacks. Right now, the fee will likely hold. If the FTC wins their case, will such chargebacks (against Adobe) likely succeed?
No-credit payment methods. Have any lawsuits to collect early termination fees been brought to court, and have any succeeded?
Business dissolution. Would closing a solvent LLC without going through the Provider's termination process be an illegal act, or do these contracts just become void once the Customer is gone?
Business bankruptcy. Where would the Provider's priority be - do ETF clauses qualify as fines, penalties and forfeitures with priority 2(d)? Or is this basically uncollectable in a bankruptcy?


In many situations, ETFs go along with discounts for long-term contracts. This is common with service providers like ISPs and cable TV. If you cancel before the end of the contract period, you essentially have to pay back the difference from what you would have owed with the month-by-month plan.

@Barmar True, in your example the fee would likely be undisputable. In other cases, you pay for the whole year even if you cancel. In Adobe's case, it's 50% of what you'd owe for the year. It's this practice that is coming into question.

@Therac: What's the distinction here? Did the person sign up for a year but agreed to pay in monthly installments? Or did they sign up for a monthtly subscription with no term? Based on Adobe's argument holding water, I'm assuming it's the former; which means that the purchase doesn't match the time of payment (which is perfectly fine if agreed to by both parties)

@Flater Like I said, I used to view this as paying in installments. In Adobe's case it's the former. But it seems that the FTC is taking a different view at least in some cases.

"Annual paid monthly" certainly seems to suggest a full-year commitment with an installment-like arrangement.  If you were just paying month to month then it would simply be a "monthly" plan.  I wouldn't think that would in itself absolve Adobe of liability, but I wouldn't be surprised if they raised it as one of the arguments in their defense.

As I read a summary of the suit, it seems less about the ETF itself than about that term of the agreement not being adequately disclosed.  That compounded by technological hurdles designed, according to the FTC, to make it hard for customers to cancel.  Overall, I think the ETF is a relatively minor detail in this case.

As I understand it, there are two separate issues. First is the ETF, and the problem here isn't that the fee exists. It's that the information about the fee was buried too far. Contract law has certain rules regarding fine print, and when things must be emphasized (this is why legalize will often have certain things ALL CAPS, for example). The second issue is making it too hard to cancel. But again: separate issue from whether ETFs are enforcable.

@JoelCoehoorn I see three issues here: 1) Was there a meeting of the minds - did the Customer knowingly commit to the fee? 2) Is this fee valid liquidation damages, or an invalid penalty clause?, and 3) Enforcement of the fee if it's legal, or of its return if not.

I wonder whether the simple 'unadvertised' in your first line makes a crucial difference here.

united-states

how strong is the legal status of such fees as of today?

There is no all or nothing answer to this question. Early termination fees aren't categorically illegal. Sometimes they are allowed and sometimes they aren't.
Also, the issue in the FTC v. Adobe case mentioned in the question, about whether the early termination fees were actually disclosed, is a separate issue which goes to whether these fees were even part of the contract between the parties, and whether the disclosure conforms to the Restore Online Shoppers' Confidence Act (ROSCA) which, basically:

prohibits any post-transaction third party seller (a seller who
markets goods or services online through an initial merchant after a
consumer has initiated a transaction with that merchant) from charging
any financial account in an Internet transaction unless it has
disclosed clearly all material terms of the transaction and obtained
the consumer's express informed consent to the charge. The seller must
obtain the number of the account to be charged directly from the
consumer.

The requirement to "clearly disclose" and to obtain "express informed consent" for a charge is a somewhat higher standard of agreement than mere contractual agreement.
Usually, the validity of these fees comes down to how easy it is to determine damages after the fact in the case of an early termination, and how big the fee is (i.e. whether it is a reasonable estimate of the harm to the company whose services were terminated early).
The basic legal issue, apart from FTC regulation and consumer protection statutes, is the common law distinction between a "liquidated damages clause" which is legal as long as it is adequately disclosed and agreed to in contract language, and a "penalty" which is void as contrary to public policy.
A liquidated damages clause is valid if the actual damages are difficult to determine with certainty and the liquidated damages amount is a reasonable estimate of what the damages are likely to be based upon what is known before the event triggering the liquidated damages payment occurs.
If the fixed dollar amount payment does not meet those standards, then it is a void penalty and unenforceable.
This distinction is laid out in the Restatement of Contracts, the current version of which is the second edition, which is an academic summary of the common law case law rules of contracts law, spelled out in statutory form, which states in the pertinent part:

The Second Restatement of Contracts, Section 356 states:
(1) Damages for breach by either party may be liquidated in the
agreement but only at an amount that is reasonable in the light of the
anticipated or actual loss caused by the breach and the difficulties
of proof of loss. A term fixing unreasonably large liquidated damages
is unenforceable on grounds of public policy as a penalty.

The Federal Trade Commission and state consumer protection statutes, often provide additional protections or clarification in specific situations.
Specific questions:


Chargebacks. Right now, the fee will likely hold. If the FTC wins their case, will such chargebacks likely succeed?


A chargeback isn't inherently more valid or less valid than a lawsuit to collect them (apart from the scope of ROSCA requirements), although a charge back puts the burden of bringing a lawsuit to change the status quo on the early terminating customer, while a lawsuit puts the burden of bringing the lawsuit on the firm. (And, while I say "lawsuit", a large share of these cases are subject to mandatory consumer arbitration clauses.)
Since the amount in dispute is often modest, the cost of bringing a lawsuit weighs heavily in the decision over whether it makes sense to litigate the issue. Usually it is only efficient for a consumer to sue in the context of a class action lawsuit, and that option is short circuited when there is an arbitration clause that prohibits class action arbitration.
Something like FTC enforcement is important, because a regulatory agency enforcement actions is an alternative to a class action lawsuit that can also be an efficient way to enforce consumer rights.


No-credit payment methods. Have any lawsuits to collect early termination fees been brought to court, and have any succeeded?


There are cases where companies have sued to collect early termination fees in court and won. Mostly, those are cases where the early termination fees are found to be valid liquidated damages clauses. When the firm suing to collect early termination fees loses, they are called penalty clauses. There are probably hundreds, if not thousands, of appellate court cases address these issues, and they are decided on a case by case basis.


Business dissolution. Property leases have to be settled for that. Do service subscriptions similarly count as outstanding obligations,
which would prevent a voluntary closure?


I can't tell what is being asked here. A dissolving business doesn't have to stay in business, it can pay money damages from whatever assets it may have instead. And, if it is a limited liability entity, the money damages that can be collected from it can't be collected from anything other than the company's assets unless the contract is guaranteed by someone else.
In a Chapter 11 business reorganization bankruptcy, the company has a choice between honoring and being bound by "executory contracts" (i.e. contracts for which at least some performance is due in the future), or abandoning the contracts and paying any money damages that result from doing so as a claim in the bankruptcy. This choice must be made by a statutory deadline.


Business bankruptcy. Where would the Provider's priority be - do ETF clauses qualify as fines, penalties and forfeitures with priority
2(d), or does that only apply to fines and penalties as opposed to
"fees"?


In a business bankruptcy, something that is a penalty at common law, is just void and unenforceable, not a debt at all. A "fine, penalty, or forfeiture" within the meaning of the priority statute of Title 11 of the United States Code (i.e. the Bankruptcy Code) refers to governmentally imposed fines, penalties, or forfeitures.

Thanks! This is exactly the kind of devil-in-the-details analysis I've been looking for. Am I correct in understanding that in a case where the cost of switching a license on/off is shown to be zero, this fee ceases being valid liquidated damages?

@Therac, keep in mind that the lost income/profits due to the customer not paying all installments weighs into the calculation of liquidated damages. It is a fair expectation for the company to receive 12 monthly installments if the customer enters into a 1-year contract with monthly payments. The company could have entered into some financial obligations of its own based on that expectation.

@BartvanIngenSchenau Sure. But I'm specifically limiting this case to where are no actual damages. Clearly, an outsource contractor losing their only customer would have massive side effects and actual damages. Adobe losing or gaining 1 out of 33 million subscriptions doesn't affect their planning.

@Therac Bart is more correct than not. Contract damages are about benefit of the bargain, not about actual harm. In the absence of a liquidated damages clause, the contract damages for terminating early would be the amount collected if payment in full was made for the remaining term of the contract reduced by the amount by which damages can be mitigated by having someone else pay for it instead, and there is a reasonable argument in a webpage context that any new customer would have been there with or without the early termination, because the available amount of services is unlimited.

@ohwilleke This is the complication. Is there a legal difference between liquidation damages stemming solely from benefit of the bargain, vs from actual harm? Would a builder whose customer went insolvent halfway through have any more options for recovering their losses, compared to a service provider with an ETF, or are both of them on equal footing?

"Is there a legal difference between liquidation damages stemming solely from benefit of the bargain, vs from actual harm?" No. In a contract context, actual harm is the benefit of the bargain less legally required mitigation of the harm by the non-breaching party.

"Would a builder whose customer went insolvent halfway through have any more options for recovering their losses, compared to a service provider with an ETF, or are both of them on equal footing?" Apples and oranges. The builder would have a mechanic's lien in the real property, but might be limited in rights of the customer went bankrupt. Hard to tell for a service provider with an autopay setup without knowing more facts. You can't get blood out of a turnip, so if there is no collateral and the customer is broke, there's not much that the service provider can do.

@Therac If there were a major loss of confidence in the company, hundreds of thousands of early terminations could have a major effect. The company's contracts with its suppliers also have early termination penalties!

@ohwilleke Adobe does have some leverage, though, as it stores their customers' creations on their servers. Can that potentially function in a similar way to a mechanic's lien for copyright seizure?

@Therac Adobe doesn't own the copyright, so they can't use it themselves. At most, it is a "mortgage your cat" transaction in which seizing it harms the customer without benefiting the enforcing party.

@grahamj42 Sure, but that would be a claim to raise in court. My question is regarding simpler cases where the Provider doesn't raise it, and seeks to collect the benefit of the bargain. A loss of confidence claim would best be brought against the FTC, since it's their lawsuit that might cause it, rather than an individual dropped contract.

Unfair contract terms (UCT) are illegal
australia
Under the Competition and Consumer Act 2010 (for goods and services) and the ASIC Act 2001 (for financial products), UCT in standard form contracts where one of the parties is a consumer or a small business may are void and their inclusion is an offence.

Contract terms are unfair if they:

cause a significant imbalance in the rights and obligations of the parties under the contract

are not reasonably necessary to protect the legitimate interests of the party who gets an advantage from the term, and

would cause financial or other harm to the other party if enforced.


In deciding whether a term is unfair, a court can consider any matters it thinks relevant but it must consider the contract as a whole and whether the term is transparent.

The law sets out examples of possibly unfair terms, including:


terms that penalise one party (but not the other) for breaching or ending the contract


So:

Adobe’s contract is a standard form contract
Many of their customers are consumers or small businesses
This term causes a significant imbalance, unless the term is symmetrical and Adobe has to pay the consumer if they end the contract, which seems unlikely
Isn’t reasonably necessary
Causes harm to the other party if enforced
Is actually used as an example of an UCT in the legislation

It wouldn’t look good for them here.

Does your analysis apply to early termination fees in general, or specifically to the one used by Adobe?

@BartvanIngenSchenau each case turns on its own facts

canada
This answer considers the general case of cancellation terms in contracts, not special statutory regimes that may apply to consumer contracts.
Consider a contract with the following terms:

A promises to pay $100 a month to B for 12 months;
B promises to make a service available to A in each of those 12 months.

Each of those obligations is mutually enforceable in contract law.
Without an early termination option, these obligations simply live on. A would be obligated to ultimately pay $1200, spread over the 12 months.
But, the contract may give A a right to get out early, and to ultimately pay less than $1200, if they do something more, such as pay more money than would otherwise be owed at an earlier date. E.g. something like:

If A pays 50% of the balance that would be owed in the remaining months, as a lump sum, A may cancel all remaining obligations in the contract.

If that were the deal, after 6 months, having paid $600 on schedule thus far, A could pay $300 at the 6-month mark to cancel all remaining obligations. They'd be out of the contract early, and will have paid $900 total.
If the terms of the early cancellation are not beneficial to the canceller, they just won't invoke that term. E.g. if the contract stipulated that an early cancellation would come at the price of $1,000,000, the would-be canceller would likely just pay their $100 per month as originally obligated. If party B tried to recover the $1,000,000, Party A would just rely on the fact that they didn't cancel.
Whether such a term is valid would be assessed under the doctrine of unconscionability, not a penalty clause analysis.

Well, in any case, my question is about the exact strength of Party B's claim, be it to the $1M or the $100/month. In US vs Adobe, the FTC appears to view cancellation as a positive right, rather than an optional service. Clearly that case is yet undecided, and might end up a landmark, but I'm interested in preexisting cases on the issue.
